# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: error on consuming api using RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-resttemplate

Getting below error on consuming api using Rest Template

here is the method i implemented

```
@GetMapping("/testapi1")
    public String testapiq(UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
        String uri = "http://xxxxx/api/TestCases/4";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<TestCase> responseTC = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, TestCase.class);
       System.out.println(responseTC.getBody());
        return "list-testcases";
    }
```

> Jun 28, 2022 12:45:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/testbuilder] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#555555;}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}-->
>
> ## Server Error
>
> ### 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>
> #### You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
>
> "] with root cause
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#555555;}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}-->
>
> ## Server Error
>
> ### 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>
> #### You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
>
> "
> at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:105)
> at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168)
> at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
> at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
> at com.sse.controller.HomeController.testapiq(HomeController.java:127)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)